# Upload image to another server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, image, file-upload

I am working on a Spring Boot application. I have image upload functionalities in the application. Until now it was needed to save the image in the same server. So I did it like below:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String upload(@RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo) throws IOException {
    
    Path currentPath = Paths.get("");       
    Path absolutePath = currentPath.toAbsolutePath();
    Path photoPath = Paths.get(absolutePath + "/photos/photo.png");
    
    byte[] photoBytes = photo.getBytes();
    Files.write(photoPath, photoBytes);
    
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Now it is needed to save the image in photos folder of another server with ip address like: 192.168.148.154

How can I save image to another server?

Comment: You need to look at what services the other server provides.  Is ot controlled by you?

Comment: yes. the other server has just tomcat server running at port 8080. I have to save the file `192.168.148.154:8080/photos` folder.

Comment: If you have private HTTP access to that server, what is stopping you from using that scheme? If there are more ways open at your storage, use those ways. Perhaps you even have the remote server storage mounted to your local server file system, thus writing directly to your local file system mount point would be fine. In any case, it depends.

Comment: You could just use a `HttpURLConnection` to forward your request to another server from the `upload` method of your first server, if you don't want to / can't do two separate frontend requests..

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use [feign](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/). It doesn't require any other spring cloud tools